# How do you combine one mesh with UV maps to the other without them combining into one?

Tags: mesh

I have my mesh here, NSFW sorry in advance.

I am trying to combine everything into one mesh so I can rig it for lethal company easier. My issue is that when I go to combine the meshes and their UV maps the meshes that have two parts like the armor braces and the eyes they combine into one.

Here I have matched the UVmap name so theoretically I can combine them without any issue.

> [image]

But when I do the armor braces combine into one mesh. Also the armor brace on the right arm has no vertices either before and after I combine it, and this is the case for all the symmetrical pieces like the eyes shoulder pads and leg braces.

I really don't understand why I can't join these meshes without this happening. I have tried splitting the mesh apart hoping that it would make the armor braces separate but it didn't changing anything.

I am very new to blender and this website.

> [image]

Comment: Maybe they have a Mirror modifier and you need to apply it before joining?

Comment: IT WORKED THANK YOU SO MUCH, it was a mirror modifier that was the issue

Answer (score 4):

Apply the *Mirror* modifier of your objects before joining, otherwise the modifier will be lost.

Comment: @Lindseylooloo Just pay attention, as the screenshot shows in the _Outliner_, the main body has a modifier as well (the blue wrench icon), obviously not a _Mirror_ modifier or otherwise the armor braces would not disappear. But maybe a _Subdivision Surface_ modifier for example. When you join the braces to the body, the modifiers of the braces will be removed (like the _Mirror_), but modifiers of the body are working on the braces now as well. So if they did not have a _Subdivision Surface_ modifier before (or one with different settings), this might change the appearance of the braces.

Comment: And if you had _Mirror_ and _Subdivision Surface_ modifiers on the braces and applied them both befpre joining, then the braces might now be sudivided one more time and might end up with twice the resolution than originally planned.